# How to play one-shot sfx along with music

Tags: android

I've got an android app where I'm playing music through mediaplayer and playing sfx using soundpool. From what I can find, mediaplayer doesn't have any callbacks to let you know when you hit certain points in a song\file, just a callback when it ends.

What is the best way to accomplish this? Should I start a thread that plays the sfx every certain amount of miliseconds? Or a while loop? Thanks

Comment: It would help if you explained a little more about 'why' you are doing this. My mind boggles - is this a piece of 'chart' music you want to intersperse with a 'foghorn' sfx every 10 seconds or so, for example? :D

Comment: Basically yes. I already know ahead of time how often (in milliseconds) that I'll want the one-shot to play.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the time lenght of your music and then use a simple timer to fire your sfx at some points (e.g. 5 seconds):

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {         
 @Override         
 public void run() {             
 //here call sfx
 }     
}, 5000);
```

Also with a count down timer you can make regular intervals and check with an if staments whether you want to play an sfx or not:

```
new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {       

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {          
   //call to my UI thread every one second      
 }       
 public void onFinish() {          
   //final call to my UI thread after 60 seconds     
 }   
}.start();
```

Comment: I tried the countdowntimer method and it basically does what I'm looking for except that it is not very accurate. When it triggers the one-shot it's playing it around 150ms too late. This could be because the speed of my dev phone (mytouch 3g) or just the code taking a bit to execute. My worry is that even if I adjusted for the delay it would be different on phones with different hardware speeds.

Comment: I am afraid, I have noticed a lag on all music keyboard programs on android. Now I know that it is 150ms! I've heard that in 2.3 version there is a more direct access to sound thefore faster...  I think that if you don't use new methods from 2.3 you can adjust this delay and it should be working pretty accurately on all phones. You can detect the android version in your code and choose different methods as well.